# How to Access an element which is inside a Control Template?

Tags: c#, wpf

I required Click event for my Images in WPF for which I defined them like this in XAML :

```
 <Button Click="Button_Click" Name="B1" x:Uid="7">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="E:\Photos\Me\DSC_0002.jpg" Name="im1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

I have 7 images declared like this, each inside a separate Button tag.

I have assigned a common Click function to all buttons and in C# I have a variable called `clickCount` to keep track of number of clicks.
Now I want to swap the position of any 2 images when user clicks on them.

How do I access the Images in C# So that I can swap them?

Answer (score 3):

You can't access them from the code behind using the name of the button. In order to accomplish this you need to set the image in the following way:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Stretch="Fill" 
       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
       Width="200"/>
```

This way you can define the image in your Model.

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Uri _ImagePath;
    public Uri ImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return _ImagePath;
        }
        set
        {
            _ImagePath = value;

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImagePath"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

I am not sure if you need MVVM to change the image with that Button Click event but for the code behind this is one of the ways:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Model ImageModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ImageModel = new Model();
        ImageModel.ImagePath = new Uri(@"/ImageSource;component/Images/Image1.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        this.DataContext = ImageModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageModel.ImagePath = new Uri(@"/ImageSource;component/Images/Image2.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
}
```

This is the easiest and fastest way to tackle this issue. If you need MVVM just raise a hand and we can get a Command instead of that Click event. 
One more thing, do you have a list of images? If so, we will have to use an `ObservableCollection<Model>` and instantiate many models in order to feed all the Buttons.

One more thing:

- ImageSource is my assembly name.
- Images is a folder created in my project.

Add your images there, set their Build Action as Resource and that should be all.